# Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от выбора был виден только один абзац?

Tags: reactjs

Дан селект и 3 абзаца. В селекте можно выбрать один из трех пунктов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от выбора на экране был виден один из трех абзацев.

```
state = {
      value: 0,
      options: [ '1', '2', '3' ],
    }
    render() {
      const { value, options } = this.state;
    
      return (
        <div>
          <select>
            {options.map((n, i) => <option value={i}>{n}</option>)}
          </select>
          <br />
          <p style={{opacity: 0}}>1 text</p>
          <p style={{opacity: 0}}>2 text</p>
          <p style={{opacity: 0}}>3 text</p>
        </div>
      );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно повесить обработчик click для каждого абзаца, которые будете выбирать, потом внутри события вызвать функции, в которой будете менять уже собственно state

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно держать в доме все 3 абзаца, в зависимости от состояния можно задать содержимое для одного и того же параграфа. Вот один из вариантов реализации

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const posts = {1: 'text1', 2: 'text2', 3: 'text3'}
  const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState(1);
  const [options] = useState([ '1', '2', '3' ])
  
  const handleSelect = ({target}) => {
    setCurrentPost(target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleSelect}>
        {options.map((n, i) => <option value={n}>{n}</option>)}
      </select>
      <p>{posts[currentPost]}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

<div id="react"></div>

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```